# How to make a android app which can send sms to a specific number inbuilt in it

Tags: android

I have done some coding but it is not working as I want. I want that there will a predefined text("hello") in programs and users can only input postfix message in edittext. Contact number should already predefined in program. In frontend, display only a edit text field should be there where users can enter their message and click on send then message will be sent to that particular default number with prefix "hello" . Please see my codes and suggest me how can I do that.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText enteredNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                enteredNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterDetail);
                sendSMS("+9151222", "HELLO "+ enteredNum);
            }
        });
    }
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your output currently? You could try sendSMS("+9151222", "HELLO " + enteredNum.getText().toString());

Comment: I hope you have declared permisssion for sending sms in manifest file.

Comment: What is the problem? Error or some wrong output? Explain it please

Comment: @AyushMaharjan thankyou brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `enteredNum` to `enteredNum.getText().toString()` in onClick handler of button.

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                enteredNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterDetail);
                sendSMS("+9151222", "HELLO "+ enteredNum.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked perfectly. Can you tell me how can i display the message received from this number only in my app ?